# Optimize multi table search

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to optimize the query below?  It requires looking through multiple tables.  Thank you in advance for your help it is appreciated.  Relevant schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `variant_bikes` (
  `variant_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bike_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`variant_id`,`bike_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `product_bikes` (
  `product_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bike_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`bike_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `cart_products` (
  `product_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=95 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `cart_product_options` (
  `option_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9040 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `cart_product_option_variants` (
  `variant_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`variant_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9040 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And SQL is:

```
select distinct p.product_id 
from cart_products p 
     left join product_bikes b on p.product_id = b.product_id where bike_id = $bike_id
or
p.product_id in (
    select product_id from cart_product_options where option_id in (
        select option_id from cart_product_option_variants where variant_id in (
            select variant_id from variant_bikes where bike_id=$bike_id
        )
    )
)
```

Edit: Short is a customer selects a bike and this selects the products which fit, either the product itself or the product option variants.  Note this code works I just want to know if there is a way to optimize it.

Comment: joins is solution for your problem

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: JOIN is the right strategy. Start join-ing one table by table and add a filter at each stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the nature to my question changed a bit the join strategy works, but is it the best answer? i.e. does it resolve my original question of it being optimized as both work:

```
select distinct p.product_id from cscart_products p 
    left join product_bikes pb on p.product_id = pb.product_id and pb.bike_id = 111
    left join cscart_product_options po on po.product_id = p.product_id
    left join cscart_product_option_variants pov on pov.option_id = po.option_id
    left join variant_bikes vb on vb.variant_id = pov.variant_id and vb.bike_id = 111
    where pb.bike_id = 111 or vb.bike_id = 111
```

This resulted in no noticeable speed boost however.  (sometimes it would return quicker, other times slower probably due to server load at the time).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from product_bikes PB
         join cart_product_options CPO on PB.PRODUCT_ID = CPO.PRODUCT_ID
         join cart_product_option_variants CPOV on CPO.OPTION_ID = CPOV.OPTION_ID
where PB.product_id = $product[product_id]
and CPOV.variant_id  in    ( $valid_variants_list )
```

Comment: That query returns an empty set when the other one returns 713 rows, repeated with the same ID but a distinct makes it 1 row.  I know it should return at least something.  But I have some other problems with the query too, I'll edit my post when I resolve it.

Comment: Try the qurey in a Query Editor like Toad. Also, try query part by part. Start with first table, add conditions that apply to it. Join next table, add conditions apply to that, so on and on.. Try a whole big query once may not make some problems easily recognizable.

Comment: Thank you for being helpful instead of hateful srini I'd give you 10,000 points if I could